# Is the SO policy on duplicates a pyramid scheme to reward seniority?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

**The Problem**

One could take the SO obsession with marking questions as duplicates to be a pyramid scheme to increase the reputation of older users who have answered questions a long time ago and want to continue to receive 'income' from successive generations of programmers struggling with a issue that could, within the realm of reason, be solved with their original answer.

**Programmers Helping Programmers?**

What I like about SO is that it is a forum for programmers to help programmers. Yet the obsession with marking questions as duplicates gets in the way of this. Specifically multiple questions may have the same answer, but if the context of the question is sufficiently different that one answer may not make sense to the OP. A restating of the answer within the context of the OP's question can not only more quickly help the OP but it gives a variety of questions and answers to review before posting one's own. Several times I have struggled to UNDERSTAND how an older answer was the answer to my question before the question was marked as duplicate and thus taken off the radar screen of potential helpers.

**Search Engine Optimization?**

Having only one answer visible also helps SEO for the original answerer. In other words as successive generations of programmers have trouble with an issue they all must ultimately mark the original answer as correct or up voted. Then they may link to it in their blogs. Further enhancing the SEO.

**My Question**

So, is part of the social design of SO to reward seniority via a pyramid scheme?

Comment: I'm inclined to downvote solely on the basis of the title of your question.  For starters, how does marking as duplicate increase *anyone's* reputation?

Comment: No, it is part of the practical design of SO to get people an answer to their question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum for programmers to help programmers. The entire premise of your question is broken.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the purpose of the site is to try to earn reputation.  That is an incorrect assumption.  Reputation is only a tool to help push the *real* goals of the site.  We don't want to hurt the goals of the site just for the sake of making the rep game more fair.

Comment: If a reasonably competent programmer can't glean an answer to their question from the purported duplicate, it's not a duplicate and shouldn't be closed as such. (That said, "reasonably competent" is relative...)

Comment: Reputation seems to be the abstraction layer that make SO work. $$ in the real world is similarly just a tool, that doesn't change the fact that it has become the end in itself.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi So we should make the site worse and decrease the quality of content on the site just so that you can earn more reputation because there are people that do things that they shouldn't so that they can earn money.  Sorry, but no.  That's not a valid justification for your proposed change.

Comment: @Servy - Not what I was saying. I have no desire for reputation. (Just look at my rep). I know engineers who ask for up votes just to hit milestones so clearly it is valuable. That is my only point. Without rep, there is no status, without status there is no way for SO users to engage their emotions. Without tying answering questions to positive emotional feedback, SO would have only questions and no answers. I have a very hard time believing that SO answerers are answering questions in line with complete selflessness and devotion to the programming arts.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi So what you're really saying is that people don't have a strong enough incentive to vote to close duplicates?  If so, that's been brought up many times in the past.  If you have a proposal for how to better encourage duplicate closures, I'd love to hear it.  Note that the "obvious" choices, such as giving rep for proposing duplicates, have major problems, generally worse than the problems they try to solve, so consider carefully.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi `I have a very hard time believing that SO answerers are answering questions in line with complete selflessness and devotion to the programming arts.`  I don't.  Plenty of people answer questions for this reason.  Look at the many other similar sites that don't have a reputation system that still manage to get people to answer thousands and thousands of questions for no (obvious) benefit to themselves.  Sure, rep is somewhat of an incentive for some people, but it's certainly not the only incentive for everyone.  They're just imaginary internet points after all.

Comment: @Servy - I sympathize, and would prefer to live in the world you describe, but I find that most SO users who mark as a duplicate are not dedicated to helping the OP to understand why their question is a duplicate. This would seem to imply that their interest is in something other than "answering questions in line with complete selflessness and devotion to the programming arts." If the were saints, they would stay around on the question until the OP understood why his/her question was a duplicate.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi Most of the people that come to SO to answer questions just for the sake of helping people are interested in finding interesting questions by people who clearly put time and effort into both writing their question and trying to solve their problem, are capable of understanding an answer to their question, are able to learn from information provided, etc.  People who come just to ask the same question that was asked 100 times so far this month tend to annoy these answerers, so they are often not nearly as interested in spending (i.e. wasting) a considerable amount of time on them.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi *"If the were saints, they would stay around on the question until the OP understood why his/her question was a duplicate."* - You are absolutely mistaken here. If someone is always giving you what you think you need, they are not doing a service to you, they cause damage. This is why there are so many spoiled children. SO is still not a charity site. We are not supposed to give personal tutoring service to anyone. Askers are (or at least should be) fully responsible for themselves.

Comment: To put @kapa's comment in other words... when someones just gives you an answer you learn absolutely nothing except how to ask someone else to give you an answer, but when they point you to a similar problem with a good answer, you are forced to actually learn from it and understand why it solves you problem.  Ultimately, they are doing you a greater service than just answering you question or holding your hand and telling you why it helps you.  Learn to figuring things out on your own and you will be much better for it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Agree. If only people listened to the advice here, and learnt asking questions. They cannot find the answer themselves because they cannot ask the right question. The problem is not with being a "noob". Here they could learn how to ask, so they would rarely need to actually post their questions. Getting answer to their bad questions will not really help them.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I understand your perspective. Yet, having substantial experience teaching and mentoring engineers I know that all minds work differently and best explanation is well tailored to the person asking the question. What I also find interesting is that given SO likes to only have one answer that SO decides to enshrine the FIRST answer rather than having a mechanism to find the best answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I always expected somebody will finally reveal our evil conspiracy.

It's time to confess. There are great minds here we simply cannot fool anymore, it seems. I give up.

There is a secret society here. Everything that happens here on Stack Overflow is a part of a big scheme. We are tricking people into giving us countless Reputation Points. One day we were planning to have so many Reputation Points that we can control the whole Internet. Using our Unlimited Number of Badges we could techically take over any government, any country.

We introduced downvoting so we can take away points from people who were trying to rebel against us. We also introduced several kinds of close-votes to control those who were too clever and tried to fight our evil hordes. Duplicates was one of our finer and more complicated plans. This is not all... but my time is over now... everything else you will have to find out yourselves.

They are coming for me. As I'm typing, I hear them crushing my door. I will pay with my life for betraying the Secret Society of Seniors... but you can still save humanity!

Comment: The question title is pure Conspiracy Theory! But I'll refrain from upvote because ^^^^^^^

Comment: At least you can laugh about it! That's something.

Comment: Kapa hasn't been seen for 14 days now. I hope nothing untoward has happened to him. People who run their mouths tend to have... accidents.

Answer (score 37):

Nope. The reason for marking duplicates can be found in [this older blog post by Joel Spolsky](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

The same questions have a tendency to keep coming up. If we weren't able to mark them as duplicates and point to one canonical question, good answers and solutions would be spread all over the site. Not only that, but experts would quickly tire of having to answer the same thing over and over again.

Points are all but meaningless, and are only a motivator to turn selfish concerns into selfless behavior. The aim of the site is to provide good, quality solutions to programming problems, and directing duplicates to canonical questions and answers does this.

Comment: The canonical question part makes sense in theory, but in practice I find that many Questions are asking anything but a canonical question. So tries to say there can only be one question and one answer for a given topic. However this flies in the face of how people program. A more flexible approach whereby duplicate questions were supported but perhaps grouped or linked to provide a facility for there to be many flavors of one question and perhaps many different, but similar, answers to those questions.

Comment: Our handling of duplicates is incompatible with "please write code for me that conforms to the following specs"-style questions. That should serve as a clue regarding our opinion of those types of question. There is no need to encourage "flavors" of the same question; this isn't [Baskin Robbins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baskin-Robbins). @guido

Comment: What you are saying is that there is no engineering solution to gracefully handle duplicates in a non-RTFM kind of way. I expect that there is.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi Then lets hear your proposal.

Comment: @Servy - That is a good question. I will think about it. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: I'd also add that for dupe closure, [comparative age doesn't really matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773): **"If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one..."** One who writes _substantially_ better question / answer is expected to "win" the dupe direction, no matter if it's newer or older

Answer (score 10):

A lot of questions actually are too broad. You can't officially close *"How to do X and then Y"* as a duplicate of *"How do I do X"* or even *"How to do X and then Z"*, because it doesn't answer Y.

We should have more canonical answers for separate issues (X, Y and Z answered separately), so the offending questions can be closed as too broad, and OP can be nudged towards the canonical Q&A's for doing X and Y using comments.

There are not enough users on SO to properly answer and review every variation of *"How to do X [and then[and then]]"*, and as I said lots of those new questions are often too broad and at least partially duplicates of others.

Some users then vote to close as a duplicate to help OP in the right direction, where just a too broad-vote without a comment wouldn't.

> Several times I have struggled to UNDERSTAND how an older answer was the answer to my question before the question was marked as duplicate

Then link to the Q&A's you found and show and explain what parts you did not understand.

So, no, we're not here to enlarge each other's e-peen, we want to build a site with questions and answers that help everyone. Yet another variance of the same theme doesn't help the site, maybe the original should be polished into a more readable form if it's that hard to understand.

Comment: More regarding questions suffering from conjunctionitis: [What if a question is an exact duplicate of the conjunction of two other questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122416)

Comment: @Josh one user can link to one duplicate, and in the C# tag for me that vote closes the question immediately. I of course can then comment with the other links that together answer OP's question, but for all that work I might as well put down answer. After all, I just should've hit "too broad"...

Comment: Agreed. If a question is closed as a duplicate "prematurely" and existing solutions are difficult to understand, the OP should show more research effort (linking to the other answers themselves) to prevent this. If the OP does not mention the other answers in the question or related comments, we cannot assume they ever read them.

Answer (score 6):

When voting to close as a duplicate, it is perfectly legitimate to use an older, inferior question as the duplicate, and the new question as the original. Seniority (of the question, or of the users who answered it) shouldn't play into the decision.